# Getting the max and min from a dictionary without using max() and min()

Tags: python, dictionary, max, min

I have a dictionary with two values (id and amount):

```
dict={5: [379], 11: [396], 6: [480], 19: [443]}
```

and I want to find the id with the max and min amount from the dictionary without using the max and min functions.

So desired output is:

```
max=6
min=5
```

Comment: share your code please.

Comment: Are your values as lists or integers?

Comment: Please explain why not `min()` and `max()`?  How about `sorted()`?

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: x[0], sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[::len(d)-1]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just calculate it with a for loop:

```py
input = {5: 379, 11: 396, 6: 480, 19: 443}

keys = input.keys()
largest_key = keys[0]

for key in keys:
    if input[key] > input[largest_key]:
        largest_key = key

print(largest_key)
```

If your values are lists, you need to chose what index to use to compare the list with. In the code below I hardcoded zero. If you want to go through the list and find the max value there, that would just be another nested loop.

```py
input = {5: [379], 11: [396], 6: [480], 19: [443]}

keys = input.keys()
largest_key = keys[0]

for key in keys:
    if input[key][0] > input[largest_key][0]:
        largest_key = key

print(largest_key)
```

To get the min you would use this exact same process but switch the operator to less than.

Comment: This will throw an error in Python 3.6 because `input.keys()` returns an Object and not a list. You should change it to `keys = list(input.keys())`

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the values of your dict and access the largest and smallest like this:

```
my_dict={5: [379], 11: [396], 6: [480], 19: [443]}


sorted_list = sorted([value for key,value in my_dict.items()])

max_val = sorted_list[-1][0]
min_val = sorted_list[0][0]

max_key = list(my_dict.keys())[list(my_dict.values()).index([max_val])]
min_key = list(my_dict.keys())[list(my_dict.values()).index([min_val])]

print(min_key, max_key)
```

Answer (score -1):

Dictionary’s in python are iterable, that is, you can go through them item by item.

In this case you could do something like

```py
for key in dict_a:
    #do something here to find the min and max
    print(key)
```